# Changing ID3 tags of music in iTunes with read-only attributes

Tags: itunes, mp3, id3, read-only

When I add an `mp3` file with read-only attributes to iTunes, iTunes does not allow me to change the file's ID3 tags or delete the file later. Removing the read-only attributes after adding the file doesn't help. If I go to the source file and delete it manually, it shows up as "missing file" with a ! sign prefixed to it in the program, and it still can't be deleted. How can I get around this? I just want to change the ID3 tags.

Comment: Well if the file is read-only, doesn't that make sense?

Comment: yeah, it does.. but it will stay read only even after you change the source file's attributes. Its forced in iTune's memory for ever and ever somehow. And i would like to think removing it from the iTunes database shouldn't have anything to do with the file being read only itself. The file should stay, but maybe i don't want to keep it in my iTunes for ever? :D hehe

Comment: I wish there was a way to have it re-check the files' attributes, or let us remove the file from the program and re-add it as write-able.

Comment: Have you tried to rescan your library?

Comment: i don't see that option sorry : (

Comment: This is in Windows or OS X?

Comment: this is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the files.
NOT CUT, copy. The copies should be editable.

Comment: This doesn't allow the OP to edit/delete the originals, though.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, when read-only music is added to iTunes by mistake have you, it stays listed in the iTunes library playlist forever.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem on Windows 7 / iTunes 10.2.1. This is probably better suited to a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet. I have some questions.

1. In **Preferences**, on the **Advanced** tab, is **Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library** checked?
2. How did you add the file to the iTunes library? Drag and drop from Windows Explorer to iTunes? From the iTunes **File** menu? With the **Automatically Add to iTunes** folder?
3. How are you trying to delete the file from the iTunes library? Right-click > Delete? <kbd>Del</kbd> on the keyboard?